# Dart/Reflectable: How to get all subclasses from an abstract base class

Tags: dart, reflection

I want to use the [Dart/reflectable](https://pub.dev/packages/reflectable) framework to find all subclasses of a specific base class and I struggle with that use case.

I have

1. An abstract base class with a few getters:

```
abstract class MyBaseClass {
    String get name;
    List<MyValueType> get values;
}
```

2. Several classes that implement `MyBaseClass`:

```
class A implements MyBaseClass {
   @override
   String name = 'AClass';
   
   @override
   List<MyValueType> = [MyValueType.X, MyValueType.Y]; 
}

class B implements MyBaseClass {
   @override
   String name = 'BClass';
   
   @override
   List<MyValueType> = []; 
}
```

My goal is to fetch all classes that implement `MyBaseClass` and read their properties.

So, I created:

```
class Reflector extends Reflectable {
  const Reflector()
      : super(invokingCapability); 
}

const reflector = const Reflector();
```

1. How do I fetch a list of classes? I only found the `InstanceMirror.reflect()` which only delivers one result, not many.
2. It is not clear, how the annotation must be set. When trying to fetch all `MyBaseClass` implementations, do I need to annotate only my abstract `MyBaseClass` or do I need to annotate classes `A` and `B` or do I need to annotate all three classes?
3. Which capabilities do I need? In my test case I got this exception: `NoSuchCapabilityError: no capability to invoke the getter "name"` but was not able to solve this.

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in support for finding all subclasses, only subtypes. This means that we'll get both `class B1 extends A {}` and `class B2 implements A {}` if we quantify over all subtypes of `A`, and then we'll need to filter out each subtype which is not also a subclass, if we wish to find just the subclasses. We'd need to think about what we want in the case where the connection is indirect and only some of the connections are `extends`. E.g., `class C1 extends B2 {}`, does that count as a subclass of `A` for the given purpose, or would only `class C2 extends B1 {}` be included?

But it seems like we're looking for all subtypes anyway: 'My goal is to fetch all classes that implement `MyBaseClass`'. So I'll assume that it's just about subtypes (so any combination of `extends` and `implements` will do). In that case we can directly use a `subtypeQuantifyCapability`.

You'll need to specify `typeRelationsCapability` if you want to call any mirror methods dealing with type relations, e.g., `superclass`, `isSubtypeOf`, and perhaps a dozen other methods.

Here's an example: https://github.com/google/reflectable.dart/blob/master/test_reflectable/test/subtype_quantify_test.dart

In order to inspect the set of classes for which there is reflection support with a specific reflector `reflector`, use `reflector.annotatedClasses`.

Example: https://github.com/google/reflectable.dart/blob/master/test_reflectable/test/annotated_classes_test.dart.

Looking at the original example: In order to include the class `MyBaseClass` as well as all subtypes (with declarations, that is, except `Never`, but including `A` and `B`), it is necessary to have the `subtypeQuantifyCapability` and somehow include support for `MyBaseClass`. The obvious and most direct way to do the latter is to have `@reflector` as metadata on the declaration of `MyBaseClass`.

The whole design of reflectable was motivated by the need to avoid a program size explosion caused by reflection support for many, many declarations in a situation where only a handful of them would actually be needed. This means that missing capabilities is a delicate and typical issue: You need to choose the included capabilities carefully, and also to annotate classes carefully, in order to avoid having this program size problem. This might not be important in this particular situation, but reflectable is still built to save space by only supporting the features that are requested (by including the corresponding capabilities in the given reflector class declaration).

In this particular case, there was no capability to invoke a getter named `name` on a given `InstanceMirror` (if it's an instance getter), a `ClassMirror` (if it is a static getter), or `LibraryMirror` (if it is a top-level getter). I'm not sure how that happened (because `invokingCapability` should cover all kinds of invocations), but please try to fix the other things and then return if this issue persists.